# What's a common solution for an alternating Cohen's kappa score when it comes to deep neuronal networks?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am fairly new to deep convolutional networks. I am using a kappa matrix to calculate my score. Right now I am checking my kappa score every 500 iterations and it looks like an increasing saw-signal.

I am using an SGD-Solver and a base-learning rate of `0.00001`. 
I have a roughly 15000 images (512x512) per class,evenly distributed, and there are 5 classes. I am using a Batchsize of 4

For validation the data set got a different distribution:

1. 73%
2. 6%
3. 15%
4. 2%
5. 2%

I have a net with 24 convolutional layers, which uses BatchNorm-Layers and alternating 3x3 and 1x1 layers between larger Convolutional  - Layers. So the structure is fairly deep.

But when it comes to the Cohen's kappa score I am not able to move over the 0.1 score, more likely the Cohen's kappa score is rising and then falling and then rising again.

Is there a common solution for this kind of behaviour ? Since I am fairly new I do not really know where to change my behaviour, like: Is my learning rate too high / too low ? Is my architecture too small / too large ? Am I using an inapropriate sovler?

For those interested: The data is from the kaggle competition for diabetic eye retinopathy. I am not taking part in the competition, it's just an interesting project.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection

[image]

This graph shows how my kappa score operates

Comment: can you please elaborate on the kappa score you are using?

Comment: The kappa score behaves in an aspect, that it is not ok to label a class 0 as a class 5 or a class 5 as a class 0. But if you label a class 4 or as a class 5 or a class 2 as class 1 it is not that bad. Technically the further you are away with your prediction from the correct class the worse the kappa score. If you need more detail I will edit my post to show the formula

Comment: in what way is it different than infogain loss?

Comment: The kappa score "punishes" when predictions are far away but disagreement between close classes are not that bad - I think this is where the loss function differs.

Comment: I am sorry, I just found out that this special Score is called "Cohens Kappa Score"